# Attach/detach vs replace fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

In the following piece of code, what's the point of using `detach`/`attach` fragments instead of just `replacing` them?

```
private void showFragment(String tag) {
  String oldTag = mSelectedTag;
  mSelectedTag = tag;
  final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
  final FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
  final Fragment oldFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(oldTag);
  final Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(tag);

  if (oldFragment != null && !tag.equals(oldTag)) {
    ft.detach(oldFragment);
  }

  if (fragment == null) {
    ft.replace(R.id.container, getContentFragment(tag), tag);
  } else {
    if (fragment.isDetached()) {
      ft.attach(fragment);
    }
  }
  ft.commit();
}
```

Why can't I just write something like this?

```
private void showFragment(String tag) {
  final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
  final FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
  ft.replace(R.id.container, getContentFragment(tag), tag);
  ft.addToBackStack(null);
  ft.commit();
}
```

`getContentFragment` method, just in case:

```
 private Fragment getContentFragment(String tag) {
   Fragment fragment = null;
   if (Frag1.TAG.equals(tag)) {
     fragment = new Frag1();
   } else if (Frag2.TAG.equals(tag)) {
     fragment = new Frag2();
   }
   return fragment;
 }
```

Comment: in my opinion both not useful. Okay it is depending on your use-case. My system is to show/hide fragments, you keep the lifecycle alive then!

Comment: that's pretty bad approach and you are simply wasting resources

Comment: @Marcin Orlowski you mean bad approach is to show/hide, to replace always, or the attach/detach/replace?

Answer (score 5):

Here's the documentation for `FragmentTransaction.detach()` (emphasis added):

> Detach the given fragment from the UI. This is the same state as when it is put on the back stack: the fragment is removed from the UI, however **its state is still being actively managed by the fragment manager**. When going into this state its view hierarchy is destroyed.

So a *detached* fragment is still "alive" inside the `FragmentManager`; its view has been destroyed but all of its logical state is preserved. So when you call `attach()`, you are getting *the same* fragment back.

`FragmentTransaction.replace()`, passing a `new` fragment, however, will cause you to wind up using two different instances of the same fragment class, rather than re-using a single instance.

Personally, I've never had a need to use `detach()` and `attach()`, and have always used `replace()`. But that doesn't mean that there isn't a place and time where they're going to be useful.

Comment: so the point is to save resources by reusing the same instance of the fragment?

Comment: I don't think that's the right way to look at it. It's more like it allows you to save information inside the fragment itself (using `onSaveInstanceState()` etc), rather than losing that information by creating a new instance.